# prolog sudoku block algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, list, prolog, sudoku

how to get all elements of the blocks in prolog? the size can change dynamic in my code, so the blocksize differs, 4x4 = 4 elements, 9x9= 9 elements etc. the blocks are cut into squares, so in 4x4 the horizontal length is round(sqrt(4))= 2 and vertical length of the block is round(sqrt(4)) = 2. and 9x9 ... sqrt(9).. so height and width of the blocks are 3. i need an algorithm to get the elements efficient.

my sudokulists are build up this way:

> L=[
>                   [4,3,1,2],
>           [2,1,4,3],
>           [3,4,2,1],
>           [1,2,3,4]
>                ],

so a list, with lists of the rows in sudoku. checking rows and columns is no problem, -> all_different check with rows, transpose the whole List, all_different check with the transposed list.

but because of the dynamic size of the sudoku, i cannot code fix code for the blocks. so anyone any idea? i thought about flatten(L) and working with offsets to get the correct blocks, but it seems pretty hard to do that this way?

please help me!

Comment: By "block", do you mean one of the nine 3x3 segments that the whole normal 9x9 sudoku is divided into?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution goes as follows (assuming you have `blocksize`x`blocksize` blocks of size `blocksize`x`blocksize` - in standard sudoku all numbers are equal, can be adjusted to match other layouts)

1. Let `a = [],...,[]` be a list of `blocksize` buckets.
2. Partition each row into `blocksize` parts.
3. Put first part into first bucket, second into second, and so on. If you reached last bucket start with first one again.
4. Flatten out `a` completely
5. Partition the result again into `blocksize`x`blocksize` blocks

In your example:

```
L=[ [4,3,1,2], [2,1,4,3], [3,4,2,1], [1,2,3,4] ]
Partitions => [[4,3] [1,2] [2,1] [4,3] [3,4] [2,1] [1,2] [3,4]]
Bucketed => [[4,3] [2,1] [3,4] [1,2]] [[1,2] [4,3] [2,1] [3,4]]
Flattened => [4,3,2,1,3,4,1,2,1,2,4,3,2,1,3,4]
Partitioned => [4,3,2,1], [3,4,1,2], [1,2,4,3], [2,1,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some simple Prolog to transpose a matrix in list-of-lists representation.  The idea is to create a new "first row" by pulling the head off each existing row, then recurse on the list of "leftover" tails.

```
transpose([[ ]|_],[ ]) :- !.
transpose(A,[H|T]) :-
    decap_List(A,H,B),
    transpose(B,T).

decap_List([ ],[ ],[ ]).
decap_List([[H|T]|Rows],[H|Hs],[T|Ts]) :-
    decap_List(Rows,Hs,Ts).
```

For example:

```
?- transpose([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],X).

X = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Note however for a generalized sudoku matrix of size *K²xK²*, you also have "all different" entries in each "box" of size *KxK* tiling the matrix.  Using you same design as before, you would also need a predicate to repackage the sudoku matrix into a list of "box" lists.

To do so only requires a further predicate to "partition" a matrix into groups of *K* rows apiece.

```
part_K_rows([ ],_,[ ]) :- !.
part_K_rows(A,K,[H|T]) :-
    get_K_rows(A,K,H,B),
    part_K_rows(B,K,T).

get_K_rows(A,0,[ ],A) :- !.
get_K_rows([H|T],K,[H|Z],B),
    J is K-1,
    get_K_rows(T,J,Z,B).
```

Applying **part_K_rows/3** to the original sudoku matrix, then transposing each of the resulting row partitions and applying **part_K_rows/3** to each of them will produce the required list of "box" lists.